# android set image in rounded cardview

Tags: android, cardview

I'm using `DialogFragment` to show image in `CardView` but I'm not getting full image as I expect.
Here is screen short [how I'm getting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVYsE.jpg). how can I fill this space.

Here is my code

```
public class dlgProfile extends DialogFragment {


MainActivity _main;
private MainActivity context;
private TextView txtBenutzerName;
private TextView txtName;
private TextView txtAdresse;
private TextView txtTaetigkeit;
private BlurredImageView ivProfile;
private final String TAG = "fragprofile";
private Question q;
private Answer a;
private TextView txtID;
private Long BenutzerID;
private String BenutzerName;
private TextView btnPhone;
private TextView btnEMail;
CircleImageView cvImg;
private ImageView btnWhatsApp;
private MainActivity.OnlineState onlineState = MainActivity.OnlineState.offline;
private TextView txtOnlineState;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (_main == null) _main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    context = _main;
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragprofile, container, false);
    txtID = v.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
    txtBenutzerName = v.findViewById(R.id.txtBenutzername);
    txtName = v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtAdresse = v.findViewById(R.id.txtAdresse);
    txtTaetigkeit = v.findViewById(R.id.txtTaetigkeitsschwerpunkte);
    txtOnlineState = v.findViewById(R.id.txtOnlineState);
    ivProfile = v.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);
    cvImg = v.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile2);
    btnPhone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnPhone);
    btnEMail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnEMail);
    btnWhatsApp = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnWhatsApp);

    if (this.BenutzerName != null) {
        try {
            setValues(this.BenutzerID, this.BenutzerName);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            lib.ShowException(TAG, context, throwable, false);
        }
    }


    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_round_corner);
    return v;
}

void setValues(final Question q, final Answer a) throws Throwable {
    JSONObject N;
    if (a == null) {
        this.onlineState = q.onlineState;
        setValues(q.BenutzerID, q.Benutzername);
       
    } else {
        this.onlineState = a.onlineState;
        setValues(a.BenutzerID, a.BenutzerName);
       
    }

}

void setValues(Long BenutzerID, String Benutzername) throws Exception {
    if (txtID == null) {
        this.BenutzerID = BenutzerID;
        this.BenutzerName = Benutzername;
        return;
    }
    JSONObject N = _main.clsHTTPS.getUser(_main.getBenutzerID(), BenutzerID);
    txtID.setText("" + BenutzerID);
    txtBenutzerName.setText(Benutzername);
    txtName.setText((N.isNull(VORNAME) ? "?" : N.getString(VORNAME)) + " " + (N.isNull(NAME) ? "?" : N.getString(NAME)));
    txtAdresse.setVisibility(BenutzerID.longValue() == _main.getBenutzerID()
            || N.getBoolean("gewerblich") ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    txtAdresse.setText((N.isNull("adresse") ? "" : N.getString("adresse")));
    txtTaetigkeit.setVisibility(BenutzerID.longValue() == _main.getBenutzerID()
            || N.getBoolean("gewerblich") ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    txtTaetigkeit.setText((N.isNull(TAETIGKEITSSCHWERPUNKTE) ? "" : N.getString(TAETIGKEITSSCHWERPUNKTE)));
    txtOnlineState.setText(this.onlineState.getStateString());
    Bitmap profile = null;
    try {
        String fname;
        fname = ".JPG";
        Bitmap in = _main.clsHTTPS.downloadProfileImage(this.getContext(), BenutzerID,
                _main.user.getLong(Constants.id), Benutzername);
        if (in != null) {
            profile = in;
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, null, e);
    }

    if (profile != null) {
        ivProfile.setImageBitmap(profile);
    }
    if (profile != null) {
        cvImg.setImageBitmap(profile);
    }
    final ContactVO contactVO = new ContactVO(N);
    if (BenutzerID.longValue() != _main.getBenutzerID() && !contactVO.isBestaetigt()
            && contactVO.isLimindoUser() && (_main.clsHTTPS.AdminID == null || _main.clsHTTPS.AdminID == 0)) {
        btnEMail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnWhatsApp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        if (contactVO.getContactEmail().length() > 3) {
            btnEMail.setTag(contactVO.getContactEmail());
            btnEMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    String[] aEmailList = {contactVO.getContactEmail()};
                    //String aEmailCCList[] = { "user3@fakehost.com","user4@fakehost.com"};
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
                    //emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                    MainActivity.dontStop++;
                    context.startActivityForResult(emailIntent, MainActivity.RGLOBAL);
                }
            });
        } else {
            btnEMail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (contactVO.getContactNumber().length() > 3) {
            btnPhone.setTag(contactVO.getContactNumber());
            btnPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String phone = contactVO.getContactNumber();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
                    MainActivity.dontStop++;
                    startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.RGLOBAL);
                }
            });
            btnWhatsApp.setTag(contactVO.getContactNumber());
            btnWhatsApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (contactVO.getContactNumber().length() > 0) {
                        String number = contactVO.getContactNumber();
                        number = number.replaceFirst("\\+", "");
                        String message = "";
                        try {
                            
                            String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number;
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                            MainActivity.dontStop++;
                            startActivityForResult(i, MainActivity.RGLOBAL);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            btnPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnWhatsApp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }


}
```

}

and here is drawable `bg_round_corner` for cardview which I'm using for showing data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

here is my xml of imageview

```
<ru.egslava.blurredview.BlurredImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/vn_logo_c02"
    app:downSampling="2"
    app:keepOriginal="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:radius="0.9" />
```

Comment: Whats your dialog layout?

Comment: `bg_round_corner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues preventing your image from going to the extreme edges of the card.

**1. Padding around all edges**

Since your background shape has padding on all four sides, it will inset all of the content by that padding. You will have a gap between your image and the edges of the card.
Removing the padding from the drawable XML (or setting padding attributes to `0dp` on the view that has this as its background drawable) will remove this gap. Then, you will need to add margins to your TextViews and other content that you still want to have a gap.

**2. Image is gravitating to the left side**

- Set `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="false"`. This causes the image to scale up uniformly in order to leave no gaps between the image and the bounds of the ImageView, and without distorting the aspect ratio. It will center the image and crop the pixels that "hang off" the edges.
- Set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` on the ImageView. This will ask it to take the full width of the card.
- Set `android:layout_height` on the ImageView. You have two options here, depending on what your goal is:

  - `wrap_content` will cause it to set its height to the height of the bitmap or drawable. This probably won't give you what you want on its own, so use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to cause it to scale the height to maintain the image's aspect ratio in relation to the width.
  - `150dp` or some other fixed height. This is probably what you want, assuming the images that will go here have the same aspect ratio.
- You probably don't ever want to combine `scaleType="centerCrop"` and `"android:adjustViewBounds="true"` because these two modes conflict with each other conceptually. `centerCrop` means "I accept that my bounds are determined by someone else and will scale my content to fit it, and crop the rest," while `adjustViewBounds` means "I will change my bounds in order to match the size of my content."

Comment: after removing padding image fill the space but not from right side. There still white space

Comment: @MansoorMalik try removing `adjustViewBounds` and set `scaleType="centerCrop"` as in #2 above.

Comment: now image is showing from left side which look like a vertical line

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try and play with the `View`'s width and height either programmatically or directly on the layout XML file.

If that doesn't do it, try alternating between the different `scaleType`s of your `ImageView` until you see the result you're looking; maybe `fitCenter` or `fitXY` might do the trick for your specific needs.

Comment: I've tried all this but this is not solution yet

Comment: Do you have a layout XML file you can share? What kind of ViewContainer are you using inside your CardView?

Comment: Oh I see. I quick read on the value `adjustViewBounds` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) seems to imply that turning this flag into true is making you `ImageView` respect the aspect ratio of your incoming image, and probably ignoring any sizing or layout constraints because of it. Try setting that to false/getting rid of the flag altogether and see if it works.

Comment: not solving. After removing `adjustViewBounds` or set to false image not showing

Comment: I cannot see the rest of your XML file, but judging by the line `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`, it seems that your `ImageView` is contained inside a `ConstraintLayout`. Make sure you add the rest of the constraints (start, end & bottom) in order to make sure the `ImageView` is properly constrained to your `ViewContainer`. Otherwise Android will think this `View` doesn't need to expand to the other ends of its parent.

Comment: I only see it constrained from the top and not from left, right or bottom, and this will not work. Perhaps the question's code is outdated.

Comment: its match parent and it'll constrained itself

Comment: That's incorrect. You have to constraint at least one vertical and one horizontal constraint for Android to accommodate your View correctly. Ideally, and as I've been trying to point out, you constraint all four directions for clarity within your XML, especially when you want a View centered within its parent.